Can I check on javaFX is the window is full screen, in front of the user and visible?
I am making an app using javaFx and wondering if there is code that tells if the java window is full screen and currently on screen as I want to know if a user minimises the window or swipes to  a different page.
Thanks :)
We looked online and found nothing.

Great question! If only some smart, buff coders could answer this for me?

“swipes to a different page” — What do you mean? A JavaFX app is not in a web browser.

I mean different page as is say swiping from the javaFX window to say OneNote or Chrome. I want to know if it's possible to know if the window is full screen and in front of the user, and can tell if the user is not.

The Stage class, a subclass of Window class, represents a regular window in a JavaFX app.

if the java window is full screen

Window#isMaximized and Window#isIconified tell you the status of the window taking over the screen or being removed from the screen, respectively.
The Window#isShowing returns true if the window is being rendered on-screen, even though it may be covered by other windows so not visible te the user.
